# Rspec, FactoryGirl: FactoryGirl.create in before(:all) isn't persisting records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to create a few records for some tests I have for my Image object.  However, it seems like they don't persist:

```
describe Image do
    before(:all) do
      for i in 0..2
        FactoryGirl.create(:image)
      end

      puts Image.count
    end

    it "blah blah blah" do
      puts Image.count
    end

    it "blah blah blah 2" do
      puts Image.count
    end
```

In the above example, the first call to `Image.count` returns 3; subsequent calls return 0.  The example works when I use `before(:each)`, however I feel like `before(:all)` should really be what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You rarely if ever want to use before(:all).  You want to use before(:each). before(:all) is run when the context/describe block begins, before(:each) is run before each spec inside it.  This is why your are getting 0 for the second and third calls.

There is another important reason that you don't want to use before(:all) which is that you don't want your tests to run together.  This means that the examples become bound together, which is an absolute no-no in testing. You should really only ever use before(:all) to set up things that are global collaborators but not the things that you are describing in the examples.

Short Answer:  Use before(:each)

Comment: So...  if before(:all) is run at the start of my describe block, shouldn't the objects created in it persist the entire describe block?  These tests I'm running test retrieval based on filters, so before(:all) IMO fits my use case the best.  There will be no modification of state between these tests.

Comment: nevermind.  I understand: The before(:all) only lasts as long as the next block.  Thus my before(:all) was only lasting one 'it'.  Thanks!

Comment: there are use-cases for `before(:all)`  e.g. http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/8-rspec-performance-improvements-with-before-allexample  Tradidional testing is talking about `arange` `act` `assert` (and `annihilate`)  basically Given When Then,  Arange part can be set up with both `before(:each)` , `before(:all)` ( but you must remember to `annihilate` part => deleting records.  . as long as the `act` part (When`) is not wrapped with `before(:all)`. Every assertion need to have it's own `act`.

Comment: ... so you can prepare some data `arrange` (before :all) then prepare some more data `arrange` with before(:each) then `Act` (in before :each, or directly inside `it` statement ,  then `Assert` the result  `it` statement

Comment: the point is `before(:all)` it's place, Developers just need to learn how to use it properly without tearing down other test when run in parallel. (e.g. isolating test with filter `describe 'test context where I use before all', :integration do`  and run one test suite with `rspec spec -t=~integration` and othere `rspec spec -t=integration`